# How to debug diverging test using QuickCheck

Tags: haskell, ghc, quickcheck

I have some parsing code using Megaparsec that I've written a simple property to test (it generates a random expression tree, pretty-prints it, and then checks that the result parses back to the original tree).

Unfortunately, there seems to be a bug and if I run the tests without any limits, I see the GHC process allocating more and more memory until either I kill it or the OOM killer gets there first.

Not a problem, I thought... but I can't for the life of me figure out what's causing the divergence. The property itself looks like this: (I've ripped out the proper testing and the shrinking code to try to minimise the code that actually runs)

```
prop_parse_expr :: Property
prop_parse_expr =
  forAll arbitrary $
  (\ pe ->
     let str = prettyParExpr 0 pe in
       counterexample ("Rendered to: " ++ show str) $
       trace ("STARTING TEST: " ++ show str) $
       case parse (expr <* eof) "" str of
         Left _ -> trace "NOPE" $ False
         Right _ -> trace "GOOD" $ True)
```

If I compile with profiling (using `stack test --profile`), I can run the resulting binary with RTS options. Ahah, I thought, and ran with `-xc`, thinking that I'd get a helpful stack trace when I sent a SIGINT to the stuck job. It seems not. Running with

```
./long/path/to/foo-test -j1 --test-seed 1 +RTS -xc
```

I see this output:

```
STARTING TEST: "0"
GOOD
STARTING TEST: "(x [( !0 )]) "
STARTING TEST: "({ 2 {( !0 )}} ) "
STARTING TEST: "{ 2{ ( x[0? {( 0) ,( x ) } :((0 )? (x ):0) -: ( -(^( x  )) ) ]), 0**( x )} } "
STARTING TEST: "| (0? (x[({ 1{ (0)? x : ( 0 ) }} ) ]) :(~&( 0) ?( x):( (x ) ^( x ) )))"
STARTING TEST: "(0 )"
STARTING TEST: "0"
^C*** Exception (reporting due to +RTS -xc): (THUNK_STATIC), stack trace: 
  Test.Framework.Improving.runImprovingIO,
  called from Test.Framework.Providers.QuickCheck2.runProperty,
  called from Test.Framework.Providers.QuickCheck2.runTest,
  called from Test.Framework.Runners.Core.runSimpleTest,
  called from Test.Framework.Runners.Core.runTestTree.go,
  called from Test.Framework.Runners.Core.runTestTree,
  called from Test.Framework.Runners.Core.runTests',
  called from Test.Framework.Runners.Core.runTests,
  called from Test.Framework.Runners.Console.defaultMainWithOpts,
  called from Test.Framework.Runners.Console.defaultMainWithArgs,
  called from Test.Framework.Runners.Console.defaultMain,
  called from Main.main
<snip: 2 more identical backtraces>
*** Exception (reporting due to +RTS -xc): (THUNK_STATIC), stack trace: 
  Test.Framework.Runners.Console.Utilities.hideCursorDuring,
  called from Test.Framework.Runners.Console.Run.showRunTestsTop,
  called from Test.Framework.Improving.runImprovingIO,
  called from Test.Framework.Providers.QuickCheck2.runProperty,
  called from Test.Framework.Providers.QuickCheck2.runTest,
  called from Test.Framework.Runners.Core.runSimpleTest,
  called from Test.Framework.Runners.Core.runTestTree.go,
  called from Test.Framework.Runners.Core.runTestTree,
  called from Test.Framework.Runners.Core.runTests',
  called from Test.Framework.Runners.Core.runTests,
  called from Test.Framework.Runners.Console.defaultMainWithOpts,
  called from Test.Framework.Runners.Console.defaultMainWithArgs,
  called from Test.Framework.Runners.Console.defaultMain,
  called from Main.main
```

Can anyone tell me:

1. Why I see multiple `STARTING TEST` lines without `GOOD` or `NOPE` between them, despite the -j1?
2. How I get an actual stack trace that shows where the test is allocating all its memory?

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: `trace "GOOD" True` has no free variables; it is most likely getting optimized and redefined as a global constant so you will see it print at most once.

Comment: It is kind of suspicious that there is no mention of your library in the stack trace. Now that you have a counterexample you might want to try isolating it in a standalone executable.

Comment: Duh... Thanks for spotting the trace problem. I'll have a proper stare at this again this evening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who finds this question, the problem with my code was that my `arbitrary` instance for expressions didn't constrain sizes properly, so sometimes tried to make enormous trees. See the "Generating Recursive Data Types" section of the [QuickCheck manual](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~rjmh/QuickCheck/manual.html) for what I should have been doing!

I found that running commands like:

```
./long/path/to/foo-test -o3 +RTS -xc
```

helped me figure out what was going on. Strangely, the backtrace still shows several threads of execution. I don't really understand why, but at least I could then see that I was spending time in my "`makeAnExpr`" function. The trick is to tune the timeout (3 seconds above) so that it doesn't kill a test until it's well and truly stuck, but does stop it before it starts eating all your RAM!